# How to store wordpress media files in Google Cloud Storage buckets?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I am using **Google Cloud platform** for my website hosting. My website mostly contains images.

I am using the persistent disc of size 50gb for storage purpose. If I increase the size of persistent disks, the cost is becoming high.

Now the drive became full. Persistent Disk is costly compared to Google Cloud Storage buckets (hereafter referred as GCSB). I want to use GCSB.

I know that GCSB is similar to Amazon S3. For S3 we have **[WP Offload S3 Lite](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/)** plugin which will help to do the media upload, but For GCSB I didn't find any plugins.

Is there any plugin or way to load media in GCSB so that I can use persistent discs only for important files and GCSB for media files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to host your WordPress media files on Google Cloud Storage, use the WP-Stateless plugin - it's free. https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-stateless/

WP-Stateless will handle keeping your WordPress media in-sync with Google Cloud Storage, and it even supports an option to delete the local file once it is successfully uploaded to Google Cloud.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the GCSFuse driver (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) to mount a GCS bucket in your filesystem.

Comment: Hi @LennertKuijpers ,
I have used this link [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/gcs-buckets) to do the fusing.
I can view the bucket in VM's ssh and able to create some files directly.
But I am not able to copy any files to it from other folders such as a persistent disk. I tried to use studio for giving permissions but it's not working.

Also, I tried to mount bucket to wp-content/uploads folder, but all the files were not accessible when mounted. Also, I have permissions problem while uploading from WordPress dashboard.

Comment: This is an expected behavior as GCSFuse restricts the file system access to the user who has mounted the file system. In order to overwrite the permissions you can use "allow_other" flag when mounting the bucket. However, keep in mind that this may have security implications. You can refer to this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#access-permissions) for more information on GCSFuse access permissions.